# R How to put For result in a way to plot

Tags: r, vector, plot

im trying to make a plot with z and y variable

```
z=seq(-10,5,length=100)

y=for (x in seq(-10,5,length=100))
if( x <= -3 ) {
print(4)
} else if( x > -3 & x <= 2 ) {
print(-x+1)
} else {
print(x^2+1)
}
plot(z,y)
```

but its fail becouse the `y` variable is Empty
how to put the result `y` inside a things so i can use it for plotting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the `for` loop like below

```
y <- z
for (k in seq_along(z)) {
  x <- z[k]
  if( x <= -3 ) {
    y[k] <- 4
  } else if( x > -3 & x <= 2 ) {
    y[k] <- -x+1
  } else {
    y[k] <- x^2+1
  }
}

plot(z,y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ifelse` which is vectorized.

```
z <- seq(-10,5,length.out = 100)
y <- ifelse(z <= -3, 4, ifelse(z >= -3 & z <= 2, -z + 1, z^2 + 1))
plot(z, y)
```